# Call rule within another rule in gralde

Tags: gradle

How can I call another rule within a rule in gradle like

```
[...]
  def path = taskName - 'updatefull'
  dependsOn updatelight${path}
[...]
```

I'd appreciate a hint, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay sorry, it was actually as easy as:

```
dependsOn "updatelight${path}"
```

Found here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_rules